# Two crossing arrows (one pointing to south, one to east)

Tags: symbols, arrows

I've seen a symbol consisting of two arrows crossing each other in computer visualistics-book.
They are orthogonal to each other and one is pointing top-down (from north to south) and the other one is pointing from left to right (or from west to east).

Does anybody know how to achieve that?
Looked into large symbol collections and did not find it.
What I've found is `\towa` from the stix package, but this one would require a rotation by 135 degrees and it looked awful then (using a rotatebox).

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps simple-minded approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\dsearrow}{\mathrlap{\,\downarrow}{\rightarrow}}
\begin{document}
$\dsearrow$ $\scriptstyle\dsearrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed a very good idea. It works fine. It does not look 100% symetrical, though, but it's fair enough.If there will not be an even better solution, I will mark this one.

Answer (score 1):

I have used necessarily `graphicx` package to rotate and reflect the symbol `\tona` (for example) that it not exists creating a `\newcommand` called `\stona` and I have resized it with `\scalebox`.

Of course you can rotate and reflect any symbol with a new command like the one I have inserted.

Here there is a short example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\stona}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{225}{\reflectbox{\scalebox{.8}[.8]{$\tona$}}}}
\begin{document}
$\neovnwarrow, \quad \neovsearrow, \quad \nwovnearrow, \quad \seovnearrow, \quad \toea, \quad \tona, \quad \tosa, \quad \towa$
\begin{equation}
 A\stona B   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `\stackinset`...works across math styles by way of `scalerel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\newcommand{\dsearrow}{\ThisStyle{\stackinset{c}{\dimexpr-3.5\LMpt+1.8pt}%
  {c}{-.5pt}{\SavedStyle\downarrow}{\SavedStyle\rightarrow}}}
\begin{document}
$\dsearrow$
$\scriptstyle\dsearrow$
$\scriptscriptstyle\dsearrow$
\end{document}
```

[image]